# Using sqlalchemy utils with fastapi and pydantic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic, typing

I'm trying to use the country type porposed by sqlalchemy_utils on an simple backend build with fastapi.

This is my schemas.py :

```
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    email: str
    email_bis : str
    country : Any

class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str



class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    is_active: bool
    items: list[Item] = []

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True
```

models.py :

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    email_bis = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    country = Column(CountryType)

    items = relationship("Item", back_populates="owner")
```

and my function called by the api :

```
def create_user(db: Session, user: schemas.UserCreate):
    fake_hashed_password = user.password + "notreallyhashed"
    db_user = models.User(email=user.email,email_bis=user.email_bis, hashed_password=fake_hashed_password,country=Country(user.country))
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user
```

I tried different things in order to use the Country type.

Last error that I had :
`pydantic_core._pydantic_core.PydanticSerializationError: Unable to serialize unknown type: <class 'sqlalchemy_utils.primitives.country.Country'>`

Thanks for helping

Gillibo

Comment: Have you install Babel?

Comment: Yes babel is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when FastAPI serializes your return value to JSON, Pydantic doesn't know how to handle the `Country` type. You could fix this with a custom serializer:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, field_serializer
from sqlalchemy_utils import Country


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    email: str
    email_bis: str
    country: Country

    @field_serializer("country")
    def serialize_country(self, country: Country, _info):
        return country.code
```